# Does a Subject safely unsubscribe its subscribers when it completes?

Tags: rxjs, subject, subject-observer

If I have this class with a subject that emits a single value during its life:

```
export class MyClass {
  myEmitter$: Subject<void> = new Subject();

  someMethod(){
    this.myEmitter$.next();
    this.myEmitter$.complete();
  }
}
```

and then in another class:

```
this.instanceOfMyClass.myEmitter.subscribe();
```

Should I unsubscribe from `instanceOfMyClass.myEmitter$`, given that the subject completes after emitting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `complete` on the subject, any subscribers will be automatically unsubscribed.

If you look at the source for the subject's [`complete` method](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.3/src/Subject.ts#L82-L94):

```ts
complete() {
  if (this.closed) {
    throw new ObjectUnsubscribedError();
  }
  this.isStopped = true;
  const { observers } = this;
  const len = observers.length;
  const copy = observers.slice();
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    copy[i].complete();
  }
  this.observers.length = 0;
}
```

You'll see that the subject calls `complete` on each of its observers. And the [*Observable Contract*](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html) states that:

> When an Observable issues an [error] or [complete] notification to its observers, this ends the subscription. Observers do not need to issue an [unsubscribe] notification to end subscriptions that are ended by the Observable in this way.